# Which SQL command should I use to replace specific values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have numeric values like below:

**0

2323

1003**

I have to replace **only single zeros** to **100**. I tried the following code but it affects the other values which include 0.

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name= replace(field_name,"0","100");
```

The values should be like below after the transaction:

**100

2323

1003**

Which SQL command should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like `UPDATE table SET field = "100" WHERE field = "0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `where` clause instead of `replace`.

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = 100
where field_name = 0
```